# How do I change a column type with Laravel schema builder?

Tags: database, laravel-4

I need to change two fields from integer to foreign key. How do I build my migration to do so?

```
Schema::create('messages', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('sender');
    $table->integer('recipient');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->longtext('body');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->integer('regarding');
});
```

I'll change `sender` to `sender_id`, `recipient` to `recipient_id` and `regarding` to `regarding_id`.

Answer (score 14):

Don't think too much about it, I'm using following code. Here I change the data type from varchar to text.

```
public function up(){
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE items MODIFY COLUMN item_description TEXT');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE items MODIFY COLUMN delivery_description TEXT');
}

public function down(){
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE items MODIFY COLUMN item_description VARCHAR(255)');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE items MODIFY COLUMN delivery_description VARCHAR(255)');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Postgres, you have to use this then:
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE items ALTER COLUMN item_description TYPE VARCHAR(20)');

Comment: This is the best answer. It's common to reach a limit of what an ORM can sensibly achieve. You need to know when raw queries are the better choice.

Comment: Not sure if it didn't exist at the time, but this is pretty bad practice now. Should use the ->change() method as seen in Chaudhry Waqas answer.

Answer (score 8):

I came across a similar problem needing to change a column type from string to integer. I managed this using two separate migrations (with a RAW sql statement in each) to get the solution.

In addition this works with Postgres and MySQL because we were in the middle of a transfer.

**The first migration:**

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('plans', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        //
        $table->mediumInteger('duration_change_type')->default(0)->after('duration');
    });

    if (Config::get('database')['default'] === 'mysql'){
        // Mysql 
        DB::statement('update plans set duration_change_type=duration');

    } else if (Config::get('database')['default'] === 'pgsql'){
        // PostgreSQL
        DB::statement('update plans set duration_change_type=duration::integer');
    }
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('plans', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        //
        $table->dropColumn('duration_change_type');
    });
}
```

**The second migration:**

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('plans', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        //
        $table->dropColumn('duration');
        $table->renameColumn('duration_change_type', 'duration');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('plans', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        // Rollback to string
        $table->string('duration_change_type')->default(0)->after('duration');
    });
    if (Config::get('database')['default'] === 'mysql'){
        // Mysql 
        DB::statement('update plans set duration_change_type=duration');

    } else if (Config::get('database')['default'] === 'pgsql'){
        // PostgreSQL
        DB::statement('update plans set duration_change_type=duration::text');
    }
}
```

Thinking on this now it could be simplified to a single migration.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change the column type or modifying length etc, just call the `change()` method

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->change();
});
```

and to rename the column

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
});
```

Comment: @JoanPicornell happy to help :)

Comment: Works. Just make sure you run `composer require doctrine/dbal` first, as per the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns)

Comment: Stuck in changing type string to integer

Comment: @AminShojaei are you calling the change method at the end of the chain?

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across the same issue and the quickest solution is to simply change the column structure on the database and then also alter the original migration to reflect the change made on the DB.

This way if the migration is ever rolled back and then up again the correct fields will be created. I can't see any downside to this as long as you make sure to accurately alter the migration.

Comment: If you deploy to only one server, it's ok, but if you deploy to 10 servers, will you go to each one individually change the column?

Comment: Bad practice. You are losing the purpose of migration. Consider the other devs working on it, their local database, they don't know about the changes and you now have to ask each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename column to something temporary with `$table->renameColumn('from', 'to');` then create new column with standard creation line for foreign key, and finally copy data from  temporary column to the new one with controller function. 
Should work, but I didnt try it, didnt have a need.

Answer (score 0):

I would just drop it and then re-add it as a different type.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5, you can use a closure such as below. That should do it in a database-agnostic way, so no need to have if-statements checking for database types.

(Note that you may need to **composer require doctrine/dbal** to do this.)

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('plans', function($t) {
        $t->renameColumn('duration_change_type', 'duration');
    });
}

public function down() {
    Schema::table('plans', function($t) {
        $t->renameColumn('duration', 'duration_change_type');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change column name by using change() function.here i have mentioned one schema table  as a example

```
     Schema::table('person', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('name')->nullable()->change();
        $table->integer('number')->nullable()->change();
        $table->integer('billing_day')->nullable()->change();
        $table->timestamps()->nullable()->change();
    });
```